# Get at least one of each type in a MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, select, subquery

I'm trying to build quite a complex query with almost no mysql experience where I return 11 players from a large database of players sorted by total 'points' scored.

However, and this is the tough bit, I need there to be at least one Goalkeeper, Three Defenders, Three Midfielders and 1 Forward in the selection to build a team from.

I've done some research and I think I need to do a subquery but they can't return more than 1 field?

Comment: This appears to be a question about combinations - not MySQL's forte. However, if you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Is it ok, if it is 4-4-2?

Comment: @SubinThomas Perhaps it's Korfball or mini football

Comment: $gkquery = "SELECT `player` FROM `mytable` WHERE `position` = 'GK' ORDER BY `point` DESC LIMIT 1";
$defquery = "SELECT `player` FROM `mytable` WHERE `position` = 'DEF' ORDER BY `point` DESC LIMIT 4";
$midquery = "SELECT `player` FROM `mytable` WHERE `position` = 'MID' ORDER BY `point` DESC LIMIT 4";
$fwdquery = "SELECT `player` FROM `mytable` WHERE `position` = 'FWD' ORDER BY `point` DESC LIMIT 2";

Comment: try like this. Do separate query for each.

Comment: You are the man, a little playing with this and I got it working, thanks!

Comment: It's for a fantasy football website where you need at least the amount that I specified of each position!